# Create a storyboard segue that isn't attached to any UI element?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to trigger a storyboard segue from a UI element which isn't in my storyboard (in this case, it's a UIAlertView). As such, I can't draw the arrow from any of the existing components in my storyboard.

What's the proper way to deal with this situation? I need a segue with an identifier, so that I can call it from the relevant UIAlertView button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add your segue by `right click + drag` from your source controller to your destination controller in your Storyboard. Then just click on the created segue and set the identifier.
You can trigger your segue programmatically like this:

```
// Note: In this example self is the source controller
// (the controller that holds the segue)
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
```

Here is a screenshot you can use as a reference:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thankyou! Didn't realise I could do it from the controller itself like this.